# Find an estimator for $\theta$ when PDF is:

Tags: self-study, estimation, maximum-likelihood, inference, likelihood

Find an estimator for $\theta$ when PDF is:
$$
f(x) =(1-\theta)\mathbb{I}_{[-1/2,0)}(x)+ (1+\theta)\mathbb{I}_{(0,1/2]}(x).
$$
I know that one way is to write the likelihood function then do Log-Likelihood and then do the derivatives in terms of $\theta$. However, with this $[-1/2,0)$ boundaries I don't know what to do.

Comment: the indicators are on the observables not on the parameter. Please add the `self-study`tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The likelihood for this model happens to be
\begin{align}
L(\theta|x_1,\ldots,x_n) &\propto \prod_{i=1}^n \{(1-\theta)\mathbb{I}_{[-1/2,0)}(x_i)+ (1+\theta)\mathbb{I}_{(0,1/2]}(x_i)\}\\
&= \prod_{i;\,x_i<0} (1-\theta)\mathbb{I}_{[-1/2,0)}(x_i) \prod_{i;\,x_i>0}(1+\theta)\mathbb{I}_{[0,1/2)}(x_i)\\
&= \underbrace{\prod_{i;\,x_i<0} (1-\theta)}_{n^-\text{ terms}}\  \underbrace{\prod_{i;\,x_i>0}(1+\theta)}_{n^+\text{ terms}}\\
&=(1-\theta)^{n⁻}(1+\theta)^{n^+}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have observed $x_1, x_2,...,x_n$. Of course, $ -1/2 \le x_i \le 1/2$ according to the definition.

Then work on $x_i< 0$, get its pdf (probability density function).

How about the situation $x_i>0$? Get the pdf under this situation.

Product all of them together, you get the likelihood function. I think you know the rest.

BTW, in you pdf, $f(0) = ?$. So need tiny modification. "Find and estimator" should be "Find an estimator". I tried to edit it, but was refused because not enough characters.